# How to fix 'invalid JSON, only supports object and array' in AdonisJS?

Tags: node.js, angular, adonis.js

I am using Adonisjs v5 and Angular 7. When I tried to upload file with formData from frontend then it throws the error

> error: invalid JSON, only supports object and array

I believe it is bodyParse error, but I have not been able to resolve it.

```
Error: invalid JSON, only supports object and array
 at parse (/Users/api/node_modules/co-body/lib/json.js:55:13)
 at AsyncFunction.module.exports [as json] (/Users/api/node_modules/co-body/lib/json.js:41:20)
 at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)"
```

Here is my Angular code:-

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
                formData.append('name', this.name);
                formData.append('image', this.image, this.image.name);

                this.api.upload("/profile", formData,)
                .subscribe((response: Response) => {
```

Here is my bodyParser config :-

```
json: {
    limit: '1mb',
    strict: true,
    types: [
      'application/json',
      'application/json-patch+json',
      'application/vnd.api+json',
      'application/csp-report'
    ]
  },
  raw: {
    types: [
      'text/*'
    ]
  },
  form: {
    types: [
      'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ]
  },
  files: {
    types: [
      'multipart/form-data'
    ],
    maxSize: '20mb',
    autoProcess: true,
    processManually: []
```

Comment: Is the error *invalid JSON, only supports object and array* coming from the client or the server?

Comment: it is coming from server.

Comment: We are also getting same issue